# How to filter issues on GitHub by issue id?

Tags: github

I need to filter issues by id. For instance, I have #1, #2, #3, #4 issues, and I need to show only 2nd and 3rd issues (#2, #3). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub provides [many ways to search for issues](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/), but no way directly to filter by a list of numbers. That's probably because in most cases it doesn't make much sense.

Instead of trying to see just issues #2 and #3, ask yourself what those issues have in common. Why are you trying to see them together, and hide the others? The answer to this question should point you in the right direction.

For example,

- if the answer is "they are both assigned to the same person", [search by assignee](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-the-assignee-of-an-issue-or-pull-request):

  ```
  assignee:Alex
  ```
- if the answer is "they are both labelled as important bugs", [search by label](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-the-labels-on-an-issue):

  ```
  label:bug label:important
  ```

There are many other ways that you can search. Finding the commonalities between the issues is the key to effective searching.

If those two issues have something else in common that isn't yet reflected in the issue tracker, you can always [add a label to them](https://help.github.com/articles/applying-labels-to-issues-and-pull-requests/) and then search by label as above.

Comment: This answer is a sensible response to the specific question the OP asked. Unfortunately, it’s not at all helpful to people who end up on this page (as I did) trying to figure out how to locate an issue with a particular ID number in Github. (I Googled “how to find an issue by number in github,” and this was the top result.) Finding an issue by number is a legitimate thing you might need to do. Luckily, it’s also very simple to do, as shown in the answers below by Jana, simkus, and glitchform.

Answer (score 27):

To show a special issue, for example issue #4, you could just write the ID in the URL like this:

https://github.com/unknown-horizons/unknown-horizons/issues/4

Comment: If you don't know whether the ID is an issue or a pull request, just type `.../issues/4` or `.../pull/4` and github will redirect you to the correct endpoint

Answer (score 9):

I would like to share a full example of how to filter by issues id

[image]

As previously mentioned you just need to type in the numbers of ID as e.g. `issue: 1 2 3` and it will filter those tickets.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on **Jana**'s answer above, you can also type the issue's ID (or several IDs) into the Filters' search bar without the hash symbol (#). For example if you want to see issues `#66` `#42` `#17`, you can just enter `66 42 17` to show only those issues.

[image]